# Extract differences between 2 rows in a generic function (Oracle Trigger)

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle10g

I'm trying to build an Oracle Function to extracts differences from 2 rows of a same (but yet unknown) rowtype. The ultimate goal is to gather changes on a trigger sending :NEW and :OLD with COLUMN_NAMES to a generic function.

As an example, I listed 3 example tables from which rows could be passed in (as first 2 parameters) to my function:

```
TABLE_A              TABLE_B              TABLE_C
-------              -------              -------
ID number(12)        ID number(12)        ID number(12)
NAME varchar2(30)    FNAME varchar2(30)   CATEGORY number(12)
DESC varchar2(100)   LNAME varchar2(30)   FAMILY number(12)
                     PHONE varchar2(24)   ACCEPTANCE date
                     DESC varchar2(200)
```

As we already know the 2 objects will contain 1 row with same number or columns (say #C), and the 3rd will contain the TABLE name, I ended up with this function specs:

```
create or replace type COL_MODIFIED is object
(
  COLUMN_NAME varchar(40),
  VALUE_A varchar2(4000),
  VALUE_B varchar2(4000),
  VALUE_TYPE VARCHAR(15),
)
/
create or replace type COLS_MODIFIED as table of COL_MODIFIED
/

function GET_MODIFS(vROW_A object, vROW_B object, vTABLE_NAME varchar2)
return COLS_MODIFIED is
begin

  <code attempts were so numerous>

end EXTRACT_CHANGES;
```

What I try to do in fact is:
    Return a COL_MODIFIED rows' table (as described) with the values of the 3 rows (parameters) side by side.  As an example, if we use a row from TABLE_B, here is what I expect as output:

```
  COLUMN_NAME  |  VALUE_A  |  VALUE_B  |  VALUE_TYPE
---------------------------------------------------------
  'LNAME'      | ''        | 'TORN'    | 'VARCHAR2(30)'
  'DESC'       | 'partial' | ''        | 'VARCHAR2(200)'
```

I already know how to get the VALUE_TYPE and tried many ways to output the 3 rows in side-by-side columns but haven't been able yet...

Any help, reference link, tip (or even solution!) would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to push that logic into the triggers.  Don't have your trigger build a complex data structure and then pass it into a generic function.   Instead, repeat the logic for each column: compare the old and new and create a `COL_MODIFIED` record if necessary.

The triggers would look very repetitive but they can be dynamically generated based on the data dictionary.  For an example, see [this classic Ask Tom thread](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:59412348055).

Beware of infinitely generic and dynamic data structures in Oracle.  There are several options, such as [ANYDATA](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/t_anydat.htm#ARPLS077), Object Relational, and XMLType.  They are interesting technologies, and each can be very useful in the right context.  But they are complicated and often lead to the [inner platform effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect).

Comment: My main goal is to prepare generic methods so I can build a simple audit system based on FGA. Therefore, as I'll need some more functions after that one to allow my policies to use one of the 3 to store what is required (user, table, column, old value, new value, time, etc) without having to maintain so many triggers (40 schemas, 60+ tables / schema to audit) over the fact that I'm not a DBA...

Comment: Unless you use Workspace Manager, Change Data Capture, Total Recall, or some other technology, you're stuck with a lot of triggers anyway.  Once you build a PL/SQL package to dynamically create a trigger based on the data dictionary, the number of triggers is irrelevant.  One problem with the link I provided is that it uses a lot of SQL*Plus commands.  That makes it look like a DBA solution.  But you can very easily replace that with pure PL/SQL - some loops, execute immediate, etc.  If I have time later I'll try to build an example.

Comment: I'm actually giving a look at Change Data Capture. It looks like I'll find all I need there (even it does not answer to my initial question...). Thanks a bunch, your help is awesome!

Comment: This link you gave me answers perfectly : [Ask Tom answer](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:59412348055)